# Windows 7 on bootable flash

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

I have two quick questions, I used the Windows USB tool to put ISO on my flash drive, but it made me delete everything first. Do you know why this is?

Also, once I have Windows on there, is it okay for me to put other things on my flash driver? Like drivers I want/like or even music? Or will it only work as bootable if just windows 7 is specially put on there?

Comment: In order to make the drive bootable this had to be done.  You can put other things on it if you want.

Comment: move them and transfer again. if you bootable it with command line before this problem not occurred

Comment: question#2, yes, I do it all the time.